# fetch only particular date mails

Tags: python, outlook, win32com, office-automation

I used following code to get 'Sent Items'. It is fetching all sent mails. I want to fetch particular date mails only.

```
import win32com.client

outlook                     =   win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folder                      =   outlook.Folders("asd@asd.com")
sent_items                  =   folder.Folders.Item("Sent Items")
sent_messages               =   sent_items.Items
for msg in sent_messages:
    received_date = msg.SentOn.strftime("%d-%m-%y")
    print(received_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class for that. In that case you can deal with items that correspond to your conditions only. Read more about them in the following articles:

- [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)

Note, to make sure that the date-time comparison string is formatted as Microsoft Outlook expects, use the `Format` function available in most programming languages (or its equivalent in your programming language). The following example creates a Jet filter to find all items that have been modified before June 12, 2022 at 3:30 PM local time.

```
criteria = "[LastModificationTime] < '" _ 
         & Format$("6/12/2022 3:30PM","General Date") & "'"
```

See [Filtering Items Using a Date-time Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-a-date-time-comparison) for more information.